# Tabulator - custom editor with blur exceeding active cell

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm working on a custom editor (dropdown with search & ajax-fetched items based on said search) and I need to keep cell in the edit mode after `blur` event.

As of Tabulator 5.1 blur must be handled either by calling `cancel` or `success`. [If that is not satisfied Tabulator cancels the edit](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/edit#edit-custom).

I've checked how [built-in Autocomplete editor](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/master/src/js/modules/Edit/defaults/editors/autocomplete.js) works around this but the solution lies around input type `search` and still adheres to this constraint.

How can this be achieved? For me personally it would make sense if the function implementing a custom editor would take an extra param `passtrough` changing the signature to `(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams, passthrough)`. We could call `passthrough()` inside `blur` event to indicate we are ok with exceeding the active cell bounds and do not want to cancel the edit.

I've tried

- not resolving blur event -> leads to fallback cancel
- calling success, cancel -> leads to their respective results
- commenting out blur handler -> results in fallback cancel too

Comment: Note: this would be solved by introducing a mechanism to disable this check: https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/d0037aac148bc041a28363d677111a8f94e5c861/src/js/modules/Edit/Edit.js#L539-L544
I've done this on my local build

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator already has a built in autocomplete editor that allows for text searching and ajax lookup.

Full details can be found in the [Editor Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/edit#edit-builtin)

If you want to build a custom editor, i would suggest your starting point should be to look at the code for the existing [select](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/master/src/js/modules/Edit/defaults/editors/select.js) and [autocomplete](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/master/src/js/modules/Edit/defaults/editors/autocomplete.js) editors to see how the do this as they already work correctly, there is no need for an additional passthrough argument.

There has been no change in behaviour to the blur event behavior on editors in any of the recent releases of Tabulator, neither v5.0 or v5.1

You will see that on lines 226 and 405 of the [select editor](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/master/src/js/modules/Edit/defaults/editors/select.js), it uses a `mousedown` event to track when a user clicks on elements relating to the editor and sets a `blurable` property to `false`, and then back to `true` a few ms later:

```js
listEl.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
blurable = false;

    setTimeout(function(){
        blurable = true;
    }, 10);
});
```

On line 559 it listens to the blur event on the editor, if the `blurrable` flag is `false`, ie someone just click on an element of the editor, then it ignores the blur event and dosnt cancel the edit

```js
input.addEventListener("blur", function(e){
    if(blurable){
        cancelItem();
    }
});
```